# How to change GRUB timeout only for the next reboot?

Tags: boot, grub2

Similarly as I change the selected GRUB option with `grub-reboot 2` which affects only the next boot, I want to change the GRUB timeout time for the next boot only. After that, the timeout value should be reset to the previous value.

How can I achieve this? I have Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of Grub's [Environment-block](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Environment-block).

We can save a variable in `/boot/grub/grubenv` and modify
the value of the variable during the next boot.

Add the following lines to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
if [ ${boot_once_timeout} != "x" ]; then
    set timeout=${boot_once_timeout}
    set boot_once_timeout=x
    save_env boot_once_timeout
fi
```

Make the file executable with `sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom`

Run `sudo update-grub`.

Now write the variable to `/boot/grub/grubenv` and reboot:

```
sudo grub-editenv - set boot_once_timeout=0
sudo grub-reboot 0
```

Don't use a text editor to write to `/boot/grub/grubenv`, only use the `grub-editenv`-command to ensure the correct size and format of the file.

You can always check the value of the variable with

```
~$ cat /boot/grub/grubenv
# GRUB Environment Block
next_entry=
boot_once_timeout=x
```

Note that this will work only if Grub is able to write to `/boot/grub/grubenv`, so if your `/boot` folder resides in a BTRFS-partition or in a LVM-volume this solution will not work.

Please also take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/896276/590937), another example which explains the use of Grub's environment-block.

Comment: Seems that's the thing.. Nice script..

Comment: I did not get exactly what you said at first, edited my grubenv with vim and ended up with an incorrect grubenv file size. You should add a warning not to edit the file directly. Other than that it's awsome. Thanks.

Comment: @kbenoit Added the warning, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first set of scripts I developed was to speed up rebooting time:

```bash
$ cat /usr/local/bin/zapboot
#! /bin/bash

# NAME: zapboot
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Perform faster reboots from Linux.
# CALL: sudo zapboot
# DATE: Created Oct 8, 2016.
# NOTE: Configuration files in Xxxx/Yyyy/Zzzz.conf

sudo sed -i 's/set\ timeout=10/set\ timeout=00/' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo reboot

$ cat /usr/local/bin/zaprestore
#! /bin/bash

# NAME: zaprestore
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Restores /boot/grub/grub.cfg to 10 second timeout.
# CALL: sudo zaprestore
# DATE: Created Oct 8, 2016.

sudo sed -i 's/set\ timeout=00/set\ timeout=10/' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

To reboot quickly type `sudo zapboot`. After logging in type `sudo zaprestore`.

In `zapboot` the command:

```bash
sed -i 's/set\ timeout=10/set\ timeout=00/' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

- Changes grub's timeout from 10 seconds to 00 seconds.
- You can not set timeout to 0 seconds because grub overrides to 10 seconds.

In `zaprestore` the command:

```bash
sed -i 's/set\ timeout=00/set\ timeout=10/' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

- Changes grub's timeout back to 10 seconds.
- Note if you've changed your system to say 5 second time out replace `10` with `5` in both scripts.
- Both scripts must be set as executable using `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/zap____`
- Where `____` is `boot` or `restore`.